# Semaphores unix c wait for zero

Tags: c, unix, semaphore, ipcs

I am trying to understand how to do a wait for zero operation in unix. I have this code, but it stops waiting always with the same value as given.

```
int main(void){

    int sem;
    struct sembuf sops[2];


    if((sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1,  IPC_CREAT | 0600))==-1){
        perror("Error semget");
        return 100;
    }

    fork();
    //printf("Empieza la accion\n");

    if(semctl(sem,0,SETVAL,2)==-1){
        printf("Error semctl\n");
        exit(100);
    }
    printf("Value: %d\n",semctl(sem,0,GETVAL));
    sops[0].sem_num=0;     
    sops[0].sem_op=-1;     
    sops[0].sem_flg=0;      

    //WAIT(0)   
    sops[1].sem_num=0;     
    sops[1].sem_op=0;     
    sops[1].sem_flg=0;
    printf("Value: %d\n",semctl(sem,0,GETVAL));

    if(semop(sem,&sops,2)<0) printf("Error semop\n");
    printf("Value: %d\n",semctl(sem,0,GETVAL));
    printf("End\n");

}
```

Comment: I believe the problem here is that your first thread calls `semop()` which will decrement the value to 1, and then wait for the value to become 0, however until that first thread returns from `semop()` the second one cannot enter it in order to decrement it again. You'll probably need to break your operations up into multiple semop() calls. I am not positive on this... I've never used semop(), I'm just reading the man page.

Answer (score 1):

Gcc complains to me about your code:

> sem.c:37: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘semop’ from incompatible pointer type
>   /usr/include/sys/sem.h:59: note: expected ‘struct sembuf *’ but argument is of type ‘struct sembuf (*)[2]’

This is the code it doesn't like:

```
    if(semop(sem,&sops,2)<0) printf("Error semop\n");
```

If I change it to

```
    if(semop(sem,sops,2)<0) printf("Error semop\n");
```

then GCC does not complain, and the program hangs indefinitely on the `semop()` call, as I would expect.

In particular, note that `semop()` applies all the specified operations as an atomic group, or not at all.  Your program could only proceed past the `semop()` call if the operations specified by the two processes were overlapped, such that the two decrements were performed first, then the two wait-for-zeroes.

Your program works about as you may have expected if I move the `SETVAL` operation before the `fork()` call, and have each process perform two separate `semop()` calls, one to decrement the semaphore, and then one to wait for it to become zero.

Comment: While a valid comment, this doesn't answer the question being asked. I admit that his English is not necessarily very clear about what he's looking for (probably ESL). I believe the problem he's having is exactly what you've confirmed is happening -- the infinite wait. It seems to me that he `fork()`s with the incorrect expectation of having the wait complete when both threads have decremented the semaphore value -- which I don't think is possible given his current approach.

Comment: @mah, fair enough.  I have updated my answer to explain the reason for the hang, it to suggest a way around it.

Comment: Thanks! But moving the SETVAL before the fork doesn't solve the probleme of the infinite wait. What more I have to do?

Comment: I told you already.  Each process must perform the decrement operation and the wait-for-zero operation with *separate* `semop()` calls.